# c++ linux Eventloop vs. sleep() vs select()

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sleep

I have an SO/DLL program that needs to sleep -> check some stuff -> sleep.

Which is the better way to perform this operation:

```
// A sleep loop
while ( true )
{ 
   sleep( 1 );   // whatever time
   if ( flag_quit ) leave;
   if ( flag_something_else ) do_whatever();
}
```

or

```
// a select loop    
while ( true )
{ 
   timeout.sec = 1.0;       // whatever time
   timeout.msec = 0;
   zeroIfTimedOut = select( fdMax, fdlist, NULL, NULL, timeout  );   
   if ( flag_quit )              break;     // leave while loop
   if ( flag_something_else )    do_whatever();
   if ( 0 == zeroIfTimedOut )    continue;
   // 
}
```

or

```
// well, however you write an event loop in c++
```

The real questions are,

- Which option is less processor intensive?
- Is there a `yield()` for both Windows and Linux that could replace
  the sleep?
- If I were to decide to use this in an application, that
  is, not in a DLL/SO, is there a better way to handle `stdin` than the
  select() method?
- Would an interruptable sleep be better in the method?
- An infinite (well, until there's input) sleep accompanies `std::cin` or `getchar()`.  Does that sleep yield the process?

Comment: Did you consider using `poll` ?

Comment: And why do you ask about less processor intensive? Most of the things happen inside the kernel.... (since all of `poll`,`sleep`,`select`, `sched_yield` are syscalls).

Comment: Also take a look at posix interval timers i.e. `timer_create` and brothers as an option.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Isn't poll() the same thing as select() plus or minus some parameter differences?

Comment: Yes, `poll` is like `select`, but google for the `C10K problem` ....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You mean, `poll` sleeps more efficient than `select`? In this question, `select` is used as portable replacement for `sleep` only. Besides, it's `epoll`, not `poll` that handles `C10K` problem.

Comment: `poll` can handle more file descriptors than `select` hence it is more C10K friendly